# Prestashop show cart summary in the bankwire payment execution page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In prestashop currently I want to show the cart summary contents in the default payment module bankwire. So lets say a user select a payment method bankwire then it will redirect to the bankwire payment page with the cart summary showing at the top of page.

So can someone tell me how to get the total cart summary contents in the bankwire payment execution page. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is already done with this **[module](http://mypresta.eu/modules/payment-process/bank-wire-with-order-summary.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

You must override or just edit bankwire/controllers/payment.php file. All you need to extend smarty variables assigned to payment excecution.tpl

```
'cart' => new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart),

'products' => $cart->getProducts(true),

'cust_currency' => $cart->id_currency,

'shipping_cost_wt' => $this->context->cart->getTotalShippingCost(),

'carrier' =>  new Carrier(intval($cart->id_carrier)),
```

And copy paste shopping cart product line.tpl file content and edit as you need. I really dont know what you need - all products, customer address, carrier or what kind of data. But if you need some data you must assign variable as I show you. For example, with this you can easy display order product list, get total shipping price and get order carrier.

Comment: What ps version? Im have made cart summary in all modules using this.

Comment: prestashop 1.6 version.

Comment: Did u try to debug? Can u see all asigned variables? If yes, so maybe u made a mistake in smarty? You can copy paste shopping-cart and shopping-cart-product-line code to your excecution file if u want same.